# Incompatible observables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, commutator, superposition, observables

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are observables satisfying $[A, B] \neq 0$, and $|\phi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $A$. Then is it necessarily the case that $|\phi\rangle$ can be expressed as a superposition of distinct eigenstates fo $B$? Or is it possible that $|\phi\rangle$ is not only an eigenstate of $A$, but also $B$, despite the fact that $A$ and $B$ do not commute?

Comment: "Or is it possible that |ϕ⟩ is not only an eigenstate of A, but also B, despite the fact that A and B do not commute?" Yes.

Comment: Yes, possible (as in the answer...), but not typical, on mathematical grounds. That is, instead of "common eigenvector", we'd have "irreducible representation", which typically would be infinite-dimensional...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take for instance $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&2&0 \\ 0&0&3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$. They don't commute, but $(1,0,0)$ is an eigenvector of both.

For a more realistic example, you could take a pair of idealized noncommuting measurements like the spin of an electron on different axes, and add an outcome representing failure to detect any particle. Any electron wavefunction that is localized far away from the experimental apparatus is an eigenvector of both operators with the eigenvalue corresponding to detection failure.

Comment: I used anticommutation as an extreme example as if $A,B$ are non-trivial and they anti-commute, then their product is completely determined by their non-trivial commutator. Supposing that a common eigenstate exists, one can derive constraints on the spectra of $A,B$, which forces a zero eigenvalue for one of them. A class of examples is easily obtainable.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. Would there be any 'physical' examples involving familiar observables such as spin, momentum, position, etc.?

Comment: @Torpido I added another example.

Answer (score 2):

For an extreme example, suppose that $\{A,B\}=0$, that is they anti-commute. Then $AB |ab\rangle = b A|ab\rangle =ba |ab\rangle = -BA |ab\rangle = -ba |ab\rangle$. This can only hold if at least one of $a,b=0$. So, even if operators anti-commute, they can share an eigenstate.

Comment: You didn't show that the state $|ab\rangle$ exists. Even if it does exist, $A$ and $B$ may commute while also anticommuting.